# TLS Handshake errors in Iran

Tags: ssl, openssl, gnutls, ssl-handshake

I live in Iran, which is a dictatorship with a lot of internet censorship. My problem is TLS Handshake error that occurs with certain internet operators (Like MTN Irancell). In certain GNU/Linux distributions, such as Debian and Arch Linux, I encounter TLS Handshake errors on many websites. There are no issues with Firefox and Curl, but the problem persists with Wget and other normal applications.

I have tested several popular distros with multiple versions. Here are the results:

❌ indicates that I encountered the error:

```
GnuTLS: Error in the pull function.

Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

✅ indicates that I did not encounter the error

```
$ wget https://ohai.social

Debian 12 ❌

Debian 12 (Docker) ❌

Debian 12.6 standard ❌

Parabola OS (Arch based) ❌

Debian 11 netinstall (in tty) ✅

Debian 11.4 standard ✅

Linux Mint 21 ✅

Alpine linux (Docker, 5MB, IN DEBIAN) ✅

Alpine linux standard 3.18 ✅

Lubuntu 23.04 ✅
```

Comment: While the topic itself is interesting it is not related to programming - and thus off-topic here. It might be more on-topic at [security.se] or superuser.com. But there is no actual question here, only the results of experiments are shown. Not sure if there is an explanation wanted, a fix, ... ? Also, it is unlikely that the currently provided details are sufficient to explain the differences. Both curl and wget can be build with various TLS libraries and it is unclear what is actually in use in your experiments. Having a packet capture (pcap files) of the experiments would be more useful.